# Keep a yaw within two yaws

Tags: java, math, rotation

I'm attempting to prevent a user from turning too far left or right but am having trouble with the YAW going from 0, to 360 at times when turning throwing off my checks.

I have one main YAW, and i want to prevent the user from changing their YAW 60/-60 from the main yaw. The main yaw is dynamic, and changes completely randomly.

Here is the code i'm currently working with (Doesn't work alright)

```
float playeryaw = passenger.yaw; //The user

float right = car.yaw + 60;
float left = car.yaw - 60;

if (right > 360) { //Some checks to insure the YAW isn't negitive or too high
    right -= 360;
} else if (right < 0) {
    right += 360;
}

if (left > 360) {
    left -= 360;
} else if (right < 0) {
    left += 360;
}

if (playeryaw < left) {
    playeryaw = left; 
} else if (playeryaw > right) {
    playeryaw = right;
}
```

Basically i want to prevent the driver of the car from looking too far from the right or left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that `right > left`. So you can't update only one bound. Anyway, I would suggest to modify `playeryaw`:

```
float playeryaw = passenger.yaw; //The user

//put playeryaw in the neighborhood of car.yaw
while(car.yaw - playeryaw > 180)
    playeryaw += 360;
while(car.yaw - playeryaw < -180)
    playeryaw -= 360;

float right = car.yaw + 60;
float left = car.yaw - 60;

if (playeryaw < left) {
    playeryaw = left; 
} else if (playeryaw > right) {
    playeryaw = right;
}

//put playeryaw in the desired range
while(playeryaw < 0)
    playeryaw += 360;
while(playeryaw > 360)
    playeryaw -= 360;
```

Depending on the values you use, the `while` statements can be switched to `if` (if you can ensure that the values differ by at most 360°).

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!